# how do I show textbox hidden in usercontrol?

Tags: c#, user-controls, textbox, show-hide

[image: screen shot of multiline text]
I have a  `usercontrol` containing a panel , it contains two set of `Textboxes` one for name and another for comments, I create the Textboxes dynamically then I hide the `textbox` used for commenting.

Here I am not able to show it `on click` event , I tried using a function called `Textbox()` , but it adds the comment box just for the first row.

This is the code for creating textbox in `usercontrol`

```
public void Textbox()
{
   TextBox[] tb1 = new TextBox[10];
   for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
   {
     tb1[i] = new TextBox();
     tb1[i].Multiline = true;
     tb1[i].Height = 10;
     tb1[i].Name = i.ToString();
     tb1[i].Location = new Point(250 + i * 90, 82);
     tb1[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 40);
     rowpanel.Controls.Add(tb1[i]);
   }
}
```

next,I do this

```
private void comment_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   add.Textbox();
}
```

When I click  `comment_btn` the comment textbox gets added to first row.
`add` is my `usercontrol`

As seen in the figure, when Add is Clicked ,Multiline textbox is added only to first row, I want it to be added to every row that is displayed on the panel, I just cant figure out how I go about doing it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You mention that it only generates a textbox for the first row, indicating you're expecting the dynamically generated comments textboxes to display on multiple rows?</s>

The code you've got there will generate the text boxes on the same row in multiple columns. The likelihood is that all 7 of your textboxes are generating correctly but you can only see the first one as the 2nd onwards are outside the bounds of your panel.

Changing the location line to

```
tb1[i].Location = new Point(250, 82 + i * 50);
```

will generate the textboxes on multiple rows rather than multiple columns and hopefully display what you are after. - Addition of screenshot indicates the above is not the problem.

**EDIT:** If each of those rows of controls is an instance of your user control, then currently you're only calling the `Textbox()` method on one of them which is why only one row is being added. You need to add a loop in your `comment_btn_Click` method which calls the `Textbox()` method on every control you've created.

e.g. Assuming your collection of user controls is on a panel called show_pnl and assuming your user controls are of type TimeRecordingControl:

```
private void comment_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Control control in show_pnl.Controls)
    {
        TimeRecordingControl timeRecordingControl = control as TimeRecordingControl;

        if(timeRecordingControl != null)
        {
            timeRecordingControl.Textbox();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, consider naming your methods in a way that indicates what they do, i.e. `CreateTextboxesForComments` rather than just `Textbox` :)

Comment: @Thuddbutt,I tried looping,I used a for loop,I increased the count value for each click,but I somehow couldn`t get it working,`add `  is a `usercontrol ` type and `Textbox() `  is a method of `usercontrol ` `AddRow ` looping is not helping,do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What part of the screen shot above is your user control? Is it the part that contains 2 drop downs and 14 textboxes in 2 rows? If it is, then you have multiple instances of that user control on your parent form and only the first one is called "add". You should be looping around the collection of controls which are of type `usercontrol` and calling `Textbox()` on each of them.

Comment: ,I know I have to loop it, but I dont know how I should go about doing it,I mentioned this in my last comment,can you please tell me how I should do it,looping around the collection of controls ,how do I do call `Textbox() ` for each `usercontrol ` type?

Comment: I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: ,It works fine,I had to change that code a little my `usercontrol` `add` was of type `AddRow` ,Thank you so much,it works now...

Comment: @thuddbutt,now I am trying to hide `Textboxes` created,I created a  method in `usercontrol` but I cant hide it,will u please guide me?

Comment: @Arjun, you should post a new question describing what you're trying to achieve ideally with some sample code of what you have which is currently not working. This will allow others to contribute and provide a possible solution.

Comment: ,The problem is the `textbox` has to be hid on first click,when clicked again it has to be shown,now show method is working but I cant hide it on click